# How to delete child element before commit transaction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to delete all shelves and book before delete library

```
public void deleteLibrary(Long library_id) {
    File fileImage = new File("");
    Library library = libraryDao.get(library_id);

    User user = userDao.get(SecurityUtil.getPricipal());
    library.deleteAllLibrarian(roleDao.getRoleByName(RoleName.LIBRARIAN));
    library.deleteAllEmployee(roleDao.getRoleByName(RoleName.EMPLOYEE));

    for(Shelf s:library.getShelves()) {
         library.delete(s);
         s.setLibrary(null); //delete shelf  // a shelf contain many book
    }

    libraryDao.delete(library); //delete library
}
```

I have an error when delete *library* because all books haven't been removed.

**deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.quangdat.entities.Book#7]**

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to delete library, but I have an error when delete it... "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.quangdat.entities.Book#7]"... delete library --> delete All shelf, delete shelf --> delete All book. But All book haven't been deleted.

Comment: In code you have shown us so far no books are being deleted.

Comment: In shelf class i have List<Book> with cascade ALL. So when i delete shelf --> All book will be deleted. But in this case books are not being deleted. Could you help me..Please!